# Mostrar/Ocultar un elemento basado en valor múltiple y no único

Tags: javascript

Quiero ocultar un `div`/elemento por ID con getElementById por varios valores de un `input`. He intentado algo como:

```
if (document.getElementById('input1').value=="a","c")
```

pero funciona solo si pongo `value=="a"` y no `value=="a","c"`. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Éste es mi código:

```js
function mostrar(){
  document.getElementById('dcdto').style.display= "block";
}

function ocultar(){
  document.getElementById('dcdto').style.display= "none";
}

function inicial(){
  if (document.getElementById('input1').value=="a") {
    mostrar() ;
  } else {
    ocultar();
  }
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="inicial()">
  <div id='dcdto'>Capa secreta</div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="input1" onChange="inicial()"/>
  </form>
</body>
```

Comment: te saludo y te sugiero revisar [ask], el titulo debe ser de mejor calidad, por que estas soltando código tanto en el título como en el cuerpo de la pregunta, trata de agregar una mejor explicación en tu pregunta dandole click en editar

Comment: Guillem, veo en tus preguntas que usas HTML4.1 transicional, ¿es por algún motivo en concreto que no usas HTML5?

Comment: Hola Àlvaro, En cuanto al HTML4.1 transicional, será porque utilizo Expresión Web 4 para maquetar, no soy muy experto en programación como habrás comprobado por la pregunta, agradecería me dijeras que mejor programa tipo visual dreamweaver seía el mejor.

Comment: En segundo lugar, gracias por la pronta respuesta, de verdad, es un placer contar con amigos desinteresados como tú...de veras...

Comment: ...Y en tercer lugar, lo acabo de probar y funciona de pu... lujo, llevo 15 días con onblures y demás sin conseguirlo...muchisiiiiimas gracias, sin adulaciones, un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Una cosa que puedes hacer es tener todos los valores en un array y luego comprobar si el valor del `input` se encuentra entre los valores del array. Para buscar los elementos dentro del array puedes usar la función [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf).

Algo como esto:

```js
function mostrar(){
  document.getElementById('dcdto').style.display= "block";
}

function ocultar(){
  document.getElementById('dcdto').style.display= "none";
}

function inicial(){
  // pones todos los valores válidos en un array
  valores = ["a", "c"];
  // compruebas si el valor del input está en el array con indexOf
  if (valores.indexOf(document.getElementById('input1').value) > -1) {
    mostrar() ;
  } else {
    ocultar();
  }
}
```

```html
<body onLoad="inicial()">
  <div id='dcdto'>Capa secreta</div>
  <form>
    <input type="text" id="input1" onChange="inicial()"/>
  </form>
</body>
```